# How to make title book is right aligned in footer?

Tags: header-footer, align

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,xcolor,lipsum}
\let\Chaptermark\chaptermark
\def\chaptermark#1{\def\Chaptername{#1}\Chaptermark{#1}}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\colorlet{myfancycolor}{black}
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \renewcommand*\footrulewidth{1pt}
    \fancyfoot[OR]{%
        \kern-3ex % all material is shifted up by 3ex
        \color{myfancycolor}
        \hrule height1pt % your \hrule
        \hfil
        \hbox{\rlap{\vrule height1.3em width2em depth.7em}% you black box
            \hbox to2em{\hss\color{white}{\textsf{\thepage}}\hss}}%
    }
    \fancyfoot[OL]{%
        \Chaptername
    }    
    \fancyfoot[EL]{%
        \kern-3ex % all material is shifted up by 3ex
        \color{myfancycolor}
        \hrule height1pt % your \hrule
        \hbox{\rlap{\vrule height1.3em width2em depth.7em}% you black box
            \hbox to2em{\hss\color{white}{\textsf{\thepage}}\hss}}%
    }
    \fancyfoot[ER]{%
        \rightmark{ 
            \footnotesize\textbf{INTRODUCTION TO MATLAB}
        }
    }
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \chapter{PREFACE}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to show the title book on footer every even page. But why with above code the title book is can't right aligned (there is space between title book and right margin)? How to make title book is right aligned in footer?

Comment: Put `%` signs at the end of the lines within your `\fancyfoot` definitions. Otherwise unwanted spaces creep in.

Comment: Oh, very very simple solution. I just knew it.